# Error al enviar el DTE al ala entidad fiscalizadora de boletas y facturas

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de enviar un DTE al SII de mi país (entidad fiscalizadora para facturas y boletas) pero cuando trato de hacer el envió se me cae al enviar el nombre del archivo
El código lo obtuve de un foro y he tratado de adaptarlo a mi proyecto pero aun asi no me funciona
He trata de enviar el parámetro en duro o como variable pero no puedo hacer que me de respuesta positiva de la entidad, ya que obtengo como respuesta que el envió del XML no esta hecho o que no hay conexión con el servicio.
Entonces necesito ayuda de como enviar el archivo del xml como parámetro para poder realizar la consulta al SII

```
    public static string Upload(string servidor, string token, string xml, string rutSender, string dvSender, string rutCompany, string dvCompany)
    {
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder("");

        body.Append("--7d23e2a11301c4");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"rutSender\"");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append(rutSender);
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("--7d23e2a11301c4");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"dvSender\"");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append(dvSender);
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("--7d23e2a11301c4");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"rutCompany\"");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append(rutCompany);
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("--7d23e2a11301c4");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"dvCompany\"");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append(dvCompany);
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("--7d23e2a11301c4");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"archivo\"; filename=\"" + nombreArchivo + "\"\r\n");
        body.Append("Content-Type: text/xml\r\n");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>");
        body.Append(xml);
        body.Append("\r\n");
        body.Append("--7d23e2a11301c4--");
        body.Append("\r\n");


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://{0}.sii.cl/cgi_dte/UPL/DTEUpload", servidor));
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/ms-excel,application/msword, */*";
        request.Referer = "thegeekproject.wordpress.com";

        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data: boundary=7d23e2a11301c4";
        request.ContentLength = body.Length;

        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "es-cl");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.Headers.Add("Cookie", string.Format("TOKEN={0}", token));

        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; PROG 1.0; Windows NT 5.0; YComp 5.0.2.4)";
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        // Escribir body en el stream del request
        request.SendChunked = true;
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(body.ToString());
        }

        // Obtener respuesta
        string respuestaSii = string.Empty;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                respuestaSii = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            }
        }

        return respuestaSii;
    }
```

Comment: Estás entregando un String `xml` dentro del body. Quieres eso o quieres incluir _el contenido_ de esa variable? Pues, como pones un encabezado xml...

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es enviar un xml con los datos del emisor y la compañia para el servicio de impuestos internos esto lo estoy haciendo en duro para obtener una respuesta pero me sale schema invalido

Comment: Sin saber un ejemplo de qué recibe el método en la variable `xml`, es bien complicado ayudarte

Comment: A que se refieren los parametros dvCompany y dvSender? Los RUT son de la compañia y del emisor respectivamente, pero los otros que son?